# How to implement consumer for voice chat app on Django?

Tags: python, json, django, sockets, django-channels

I am currently working on a voice chat app as a personal project and this app will be like Discord, where users can hop into a chat room and start talking to people in that room. I am only going to make it voice only for now (I will implement text messaging later). I have been looking at examples on Github and I am having a little trouble with how to make the Consumer.

Here is what I have right now:

```
import json

from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

class VoiceConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):

        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']

        self.room_group_name = "chat_%s" % self.room_name

        # join the room
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name, self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, closed_code):

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name, self.channel_name
        )

    def receive(self, text_data):

        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)

        # Ask about this, how to receive voice ?
        voice_message = text_data_json['message']

        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name, {'type' : 'chat_message', 'message': voice_message}
        )
```

As you see, I am confused about the text_data_json['message'] part. This is based off an example I have seen where someone implements messages, but I want to implement voice only. What do I change about this to where I can implement voice only ?

```
text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
   
# Ask about this, how to receive voice ?
voice_message = text_data_json['message']
    
async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
              self.room_group_name, {'type' : 'chat_message', 'message': voice_message}
            )
```

I haven't seen any examples that do this for voice only.

Answer (score 0):

Send audio bytes as Base64 string

Comment: So sorry to bother you, but can you show me code of what this looks like ? A small example would be great, thanks